# File watcher in shell

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to keep two directories synchronized with the same files in them.

Files are dropped into Directory A throughout the day. I would like to create a file watcher script that will copy files from Directory A to Directory B as soon as they are dropped.

My thought was to run the job every minute and simply copy everything that dropped in the last minute, but I am wondering if there is a better solution out there.

I'm running MKS toolkit under Windows. Different servers, same operating system.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: Are the two directories on the same filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, you can hook into the kernel using the inotify API to get notified if something in a folder changes. There are command line versions like [inotifywatch(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) as well.

To copy the files, I suggest to use `rsync(1)`: it is clever, knows how to clean up after itself and it will create new files hidden while they are copied so users and programs are less likely to pick them up before they are complete.